# Использование .Net из Python

Tags: python, .net

Добрый день.
Возникла необходимость использовать библиотеку .NET из Python. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 6):

1. Можно использовать [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/).
2. При помощи .NET создать исполняемый exe файл, через который вызывать требуемый функционал, например используя StdIn и StdOut.

Comment: 2 - лучше уж компилировать в dll и импортировать функции оттуда.

Comment: @insolor второй случай применяется, когда питон сделан не на .NET технологии. Иначе как импортировать функции из .NET библиотеки?

Comment: Я не специалист по .NET технологии, но я встречал dll, скомпилированную из Си кода в .NET, и успешно импортируемую из нативного кода на C++.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet).

pythonnet - это библиотека для python, которая по функционалу не уступает [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/), но в плане простоты использования (никакой компиляции и тд) в связке с CPython для меня является предпочтительней.